# $L^p$ inequality for "positively correlated" random variables

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Suppose that we have $m$ complex-valued random variables $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_m$ and assume the following "positive correlation" property: for all non-negative integers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m$ we have
$$
\mathbb E(\xi_1^{\alpha_1}\overline{\xi_1^{\beta_1}}\ldots \xi_m^{\alpha_m}\overline{\xi_m^{\beta_m}})\geq 0.
$$
Now take any complex numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ with $\max_i|a_i|\leq 1$ and set
$$
M_p(a)=\mathbb E\left|a_1\xi_1+\ldots+a_m\xi_m\right|^p.
$$
When $p=2k$ and $k$ is a positive integer, $M_p(a)$ is a polynomial in $a_i$ and $\overline{a_i}$ with non-negative coefficients, therefore
$$
M_{p}(a)\leq M_{p}(1,1,\ldots,1).
$$
My question is: will this inequality hold for all real $p\geq 2$? And if not, what if we take $\xi_j=\exp(i\lambda_j N)$, where $\lambda_j$ are real and $N$ is (the same for different $j$) standard normally distributed variable?

Comment: A consequence of that would be that for any trigonometric polynomial $P_c(t)=\sum_k c_ke^{2\pi ikt}$ with arbitrary complex coefficients, we have $\|P_c\|_p\le \|P_{|c|}\|_p$. As far as I remember, this is false unless $p=2k$, but I cannot find the reference right now ;-(

Comment: Found it: R. P. Boas, Majorant problems for Fourier series, J. d'Analyse Math., 10 (1962-3), 253-271.

Comment: @fedja, oh wow, everything is so much worse than I expected! You can turn this into an answer, I would accept

Comment: If such expectations are all real, does not it yield that $\xi$'s are real themselves?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, no, see the last sentence of the question